# Exception in Boost library when running bitcoind.exe

Tags: bitcoind, error, datadir

I've built Bitcoin 0.8.6 on Windows 32bit using mingw32 and now trying to execute bitcoind.exe in the prompt using the following command:

bitcoind.exe -datadir="e:/BitcoinDataTest"

I'm getting the exception "N5boost10filesystem16filesystem_errorE" related to Boost. Can anybody help me to solve this issue? Thanks.

Output:

```
Bitcoin version v0.8.6.0-g03a7d67-beta (Thu, 5 Dec 2013 13:11:26 +0100)
Using OpenSSL version OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
Default data directory C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\AppData\Bitcoin
Using data directory e:\bitcoindatatest
Using at most 125 connections (2048 file descriptors available)
Using 2 threads for script verification
init message: Verifying wallet...
dbenv.open LogDir=e:\bitcoindatatest\database ErrorFile=e:\bitcoindatatest\db.lo
g
************************
EXCEPTION: N5boost10filesystem16filesystem_errorE
boost::filesystem::status: The operation was concluded with success: "e:\bitcoindatatst\wallet.dat" C:\mybitcoin\bitcoind.exe in AppInit()

************************
EXCEPTION: N5boost10filesystem16filesystem_errorE
boost::filesystem::status: The operation was concluded with success: "e:\bitcoindatatst\wallet.dat" C:\mybitcoin\bitcoind.exe in AppInit()

Shutdown : In progress...
Flush(false)
DBFlush(false) ended               0ms
StopNode()
Flushed 0 addresses to peers.dat  0ms
Flush(true)
DBFlush(true) ended               0ms
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::filesystem::filesystem_error'
  what():  boost::filesystem::remove: The operation was concluded with success: "e:\bitcoindatatest\bitcoind.pid"

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Comment: Does the available Windows binary have the same problem, or is this something specific to your build?

Comment: The official binary client works fine on my Windows. I think the problem is related to my build only. It's fun because it shows an exception but at the same time it shows a successful message.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an individual programming problem.